# Extracting deigits with comma inside before exact match python regex?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am using python3 and trying to extract a specific part of a string with regex.
This is the string:

```
data = "'Star Wars: The Last Jedi (Theatrical Version)MPAA Rating: PG-13 (Parents Strongly Cautioned)|Closed Caption3.8 out of 5 stars4,738Prime Videofrom$2.99$2.99to rentStarring:Oscar Isaac,Mark Hamill,Daisy RidleyandJohn BoyegaDirected by:Rian JohnsonRuntime:151 minutes'"
```

What is the best way to extract the number only the number: "4,738" which will always come before: "Prime Videofrom$"?
Here is my code:

```
import re
data = "'Star Wars: The Last Jedi (Theatrical Version)MPAA Rating: PG-13 (Parents Strongly Cautioned)|Closed Caption3.8 out of 5 stars4,738Prime Videofrom$2.99$2.99to rentStarring:Oscar Isaac,Mark Hamill,Daisy RidleyandJohn BoyegaDirected by:Rian JohnsonRuntime:151 minutes'"
reviews = re.findall("[stars][\d,]+\$",data)
print(reviews)
```

But I get an empty list:

```
[]
```

How do I extract the digits only included of comma before that exact match?

Comment: `reviews = re.findall("(\d+,?\d*)Prime Videofrom\$",data)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) is optimal for a single match:

considering your condition "*extract the digits only included of comma before that exact match*"

```
import re

data = "'Star Wars: The Last Jedi (Theatrical Version)MPAA Rating: PG-13 (Parents Strongly Cautioned)|Closed Caption3.8 out of 5 stars4,738Prime Videofrom$2.99$2.99to rentStarring:Oscar Isaac,Mark Hamill,Daisy RidleyandJohn BoyegaDirected by:Rian JohnsonRuntime:151 minutes'"
m = re.search(r"\d+,\d+(?=Prime Videofrom\$)", data)
reviews = m.group() if m else m
print(reviews)   # 4,738
```

---

- `(?=Prime Videofrom\$)` - lookahead position assertion, ensures that the preceding match (number sequence) is followed by `Prime Videofrom$`

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
import re
data = "'Star Wars: The Last Jedi (Theatrical Version)MPAA Rating: PG-13 (Parents Strongly Cautioned)|Closed Caption3.8 out of 5 stars4,738Prime Videofrom$2.99$2.99to rentStarring:Oscar Isaac,Mark Hamill,Daisy RidleyandJohn BoyegaDirected by:Rian JohnsonRuntime:151 minutes'"
reviews = re.findall("(\d+,?\d*)Prime Videofrom\$",data)
print(reviews)   # -->['4,738']
```